# Use Generic flow types in React component Props and instantiate generic component>

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, react-props

I have a Flow generics vs React Components issue, which I haven't been able to find the answer to, on google.

I want to make a generic component with props that takes generic arguments, and instantiate that in a render() method. No luck so far - my minimal example code is here:

[Try it out](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChyB6CuAEWE0ySIDt41cQVmATAZzkzQ43eoxZsIrJAA8YvUjACeYJHAAKKRSCSsAwhy584AXgJhN+OAB8CRAFZIS1ggFdmL3km5klKuLpRYfRBOHn5TfDQAC0cAawgXGEsbfCRwJTJyX1Vg0O4AHlzDABVlJAA+EzgAb1IASA8mAEluAC44XhgoYGYAcwAaUjg4OvYQw3ainlKVQYBfSmo1HDB+ABskeBgYuDHIZh0tlFjVEQYmQ7hs-ghMXYMwhTL1Fd5Ch+4Ziqra0Y-eSYfd7jaZlcoAbQAuqQFos4MUdlNuAAhRIwST8PaSS68KIJNbcOAAI1UjUJgigHR0Ij6cAAboFgAlMf9hEgVDwer04JJ7lJZAA6UhoNYoXj8JGomDo5hvJFfSoyGDU-jIdAwAXBfaHfLLCCrYF5BWVX4sbhMAAUAEoakNhvaiDAXFBmHALXbhnV8iI6eV6nU6siADIAQWDIY99uG+QoPr9UajVsjC1hVDgUrgzAgcDWLjQsTgPULspgXBgwBQ5dpKA6KjQ9GAaCuz1uV0RHylMv4vR0TEb-Q62cwgWFGPgGi0h0laIxVWtJkqNUdztd0+lGN1mm0en+5Vh2XUW6nklLPSYetWPzgjSgLXanW6tIWIrF-An25g+lYKDPlKVKsQYgNS1bFWE3Scd2-X8L14E16jNS0bVqNN7TqZcXTdUgUM9L040NQxOw3d9jxBPhKjGPJeGMapwWqG87zgABGAcKLydp8HMRR8DmAc6M8W82gAJhYj52PsRwkjmSE5jgChyhjOMsOoBNhiTKM0M2FdMPU3DgF9cCPzXLt7lIqjqjgWj6LaJiRJCNizAsHiais1phJM+zCCQBwSCkuAZLkhS9PjFS4DU+0U1IIA)

```javascript
import React from 'react'


// Different commands for different contexts
type PaymentCommands = 'pay' | 'reject' | 'unused'
type CartCommands = 'checkout' | 'empty'


type Command<CommandType> = {
  userId: string,
  command: CommandType,
}

// Props let the component take different types of commands
type Props<CommandType> = {
  commands: Command<CommandType>[]
}


// The CommandButtons component should be used for sending various commands depending on context.
class CommandButtons<CommandType> extends React.Component<Props<CommandType>> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        BLABLA
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// But no luck in instantiating a specific type of the CommandButtons generic, so far
const PaymentCommandButtons = () =>  {return CommandButtons<PaymentCommands>}

type PaymentContainerProps = { userId: string }
class PaymentContainer extends React.Component<PaymentContainerProps> {
  render() {
//      return (
//          <div><CommandButtons<PaymentCommands> commands={[{userId: 1, commmand: 'pay'}, {userId:2, command: 'reject'}]} /></div>
//        )
    return (
       <div><PaymentCommandButtons commands={ [{userId: 1, commmand: 'pay'}, {userId:2, command: 'reject'}] } /></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like this!

```
const PaymentCommandButtons = (props: Props<PaymentCommands>) => <CommandButtons { ...props } />
```